# Display of times (input in H/MM/SS format) in Excel but suppressing the hour display if it is zero

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to input some elapsed times. The times will either be hmmss (ie no hour greater than 9) or just mmss (ie no hours).

Is it possible to apply a format to the cells such that, for the hours, the digits 1 to 9 will display as entered (eg an input of 1:04:03 will show as that) or if you enter 0 for the hours you will simply get get a display of minutes and seconds, for example, an input of 0:53:33 will display as 53:33?

Thanks.

John

Answer (score 0):

Try a custom format with:

```
[>=1][h]:mm:ss;mm:ss
```